# Question about the proof of $d(\omega \wedge \mu) = d\omega\wedge \mu + (-1)^k\omega \wedge d\mu$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

In John M. Lee's *Introduction to smooth manifolds* on p. 217 he proves the equality

$$d(\omega \wedge \mu) = d\omega\wedge \mu + (-1)^k\omega \wedge d\mu$$

I just don't understand a step in his proof and I can't get my head around it:

The crucial part is here:

$$(g\,df+f\,dg)\wedge dx^I\wedge dx^J = (df\wedge dx^I) \wedge (g\,dx^J) + (-1)^k(f\,dx^I)\wedge (dg\wedge dx^J)$$

I simply don't understand how we obtain the right hand side. What I did was:

$$(g\,df+f\,dg)\wedge dx^I\wedge dx^J = (g\,df)dx^I\wedge dx^J + (f\,dg)dx^I\wedge dx^J$$

How exactly do I get from my right hand side to the desired one? I know about the anticommutativity of the wedge product, but I just don't get why

$(g\,df)dx^I\wedge dx^J$ becomes (or is equal to) $(df\wedge dx^I) \wedge (g\,dx^J)$

whereas

$(f\,dg)dx^I\wedge dx^J$ all of a sudden takes care of the anticommutativity and turns into $(-1)^k(f\,dx^I)\wedge (dg\wedge dx^J)$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you search before posting? This has been answered here before. To switch a function ($0$-form) introduces no sign, but to switch a $1$-form and a $k$-form introduces $(-1)^k$.

Comment: Yes, i do. I've actually tried to understand your proposed solution in the other question from a few years ago, but the question remained the same. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, what in the world do you want other than the correct answer? You need to be a lot more explicit with your question. “Thanks anyway.”

Comment: Your hint that switching $0$-forms introduce no signs was already quite helpful. But i couldn't extract that information from the other threads. That was the missing piece.

Comment: I apologize if i failed showing sings of appreciation.

Comment: Well, you made it sound like my comment explained nothing, rather than saying that it solved the issue. Why not pose your question quite explicitly and ask about that one term? Most everyone gets stuck on the other term.

Comment: Oh no, i'm really sorry for that. That was certainly never my intention. I was just tired working for hours on problems and frustrated i got stuck at this point, i failed to extract the information you gave in your comment from the other threads. That was exactly what i missed the entire time. Therefore, thank you very much @TedShifrin. Your comment was indeed perfectly helpful. I should take a break now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ted Shifrin mentioned, switching a 1-form and a $k$-form introduces $(-1)^k$. In general, if $\omega$ is a $k$-form and $\mu$ is a $l$-form, then $$\omega\wedge\mu=(-1)^{kl}\mu\wedge\omega.$$

We can show it for $\omega=dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_k$ and $\mu=dx_{k+1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{k+l}$ and extend linearly.

To switch from $\omega\wedge\mu$ to $\mu\wedge\omega$, we have to pass $dx_k$ through all $l$ factors of $\mu$, so we get $$\omega\wedge\mu=(-1)^l dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{k-1}\wedge \mu\wedge dx_k$$

We repeat this for $k$ many factors, so $\omega\wedge\mu=(-1)^{kl}\mu\wedge\omega.$

Comment: In your proof, $dg$ is a 1-form and $x_I$ is a $k$-form.

Comment: Use $x_I$ as a shorthand for $dx^I$ is truly going to add confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ndhanson3. I will accept once i took a break.

Comment: Hello @ndhanson3, one remaining question, in the proposed solution we expressed the product rule for $fg$ via $gdf + fdg$, would it also work if we had written $(df)g+f(dg)$?

Comment: Yes, because polynomials $f,g$ are 0 forms, which commute with all $k$-forms.